# How to define 'special' behavior for composite function in `.hs` file?

Tags: haskell

Composition is very normal in Haskell, but I just know that I can define *special* behavior of a composite function, says

```
Prelude> (floor . sqrt) (10^55)
3162277660168379365112938496
Prelude> let (floor . sqrt) n | n < 2 = n | otherwise = head $ dropWhile (\x -> x^2 > n) $ iterate (\x -> (x + n `div` x) `div` 2) (n `div` 2)
Prelude> (floor . sqrt) (10^55)
3162277660168379331998893544
```

The result from *special* define function is correct (because of floating point error in the first one).

Now I want to do the same inside `.hs` file, like

```
(floor . sqrt) n
    | n < 2 = n
    | otherwise = head $ dropWhile (\x -> x^2 > n)
                       $ iterate (\x -> (x + n `div` x) `div` 2) (n `div` 2)

main = do
    print $ (floor . sqrt) (10^55)
```

This time `ghc` yelling at me

```
Ambiguous occurrence `.'
It could refer to either `Main..', defined at me.hs:1:8
                      or `Prelude..',
                         imported from `Prelude' at me.hs:1:1
                         (and originally defined in `GHC.Base')
```

So does it possible to define function like this in `.hs` file? (Define it inside `main` with `let` is okey, however).

Comment: You can't do it.  `(floor . sqrt) n` treats `floor` and  `sqrt` as variables, not functions, so this should work for all functions, which happen to be called `floor` and `sqrt` in this definition.  Might as well have said `(g . f) n`.    As for your ad-hoc specialization, this is not possible in Haskell, you'll have to get what you need some other way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, your example in GHCi is not defining a special composition of `floor` and `sqrt`. Instead, it's defining an operator `(.)` which takes three arguments named `floor`, `sqrt`, and `n` and hides the existing standard function named `(.)`.

You then apply your new function to the standard library functions `floor` and `sqrt`, which become the parameters with the same names in your new `(.)` function.

The error you get is because a top-level definition does not automatically hide the existing definition, and anyway that's clearly not what you actually want to do.

Now, you can certainly define an entirely new function (hopefully with its own name, as in groovy's answer) to do your specialized `floor . sqrt` function, but there's no way in Haskell itself to define it as a specialized version of the existing functions.

What you might be thinking of, and is possible, is using [compiler pragma rewrite rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html) in GHC to automatically replace specific expressions with equivalent, improved versions. You should be careful that your rewritten form gives the same answer as what it replaces, though. Otherwise you're risking some really baffling debugging sessions.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
floorSqrt n
    | n < 2     = n
    | otherwise = head $ dropWhile (\x -> x^2 > n)
                       $ iterate (\x -> (x + n `div` x) `div` 2) (n `div` 2)

main = do
    print $ floorSqrt (10^55)
```

Comment: I just want to experimental some concept, that is usual way I'am doing right now.